# Cannot change microsoft office 2019 language into English

Tags: microsoft-office, language, microsoft

I have bought and downloaded Microsoft Office 2019 from the international site (where the site language is English) of software-guru.shop - hopefully, a legitimate product. I received a key to download Microsoft Office. The version downloaded was DE_Office_2019_Standard_64Bit_v.exe. This was a version in the German language, presumably because I downloaded it in Germany.

I understand some basic German, enough to get through the installation process with help from google translate. I have then tried to change the language by going into Datei>Optionen>Sprache. Under all the options Englisch (Vereinigtes Königreich) Standardeinstellung was already preselected, i.e. my standard Microsoft Windows language.

However, even after deleting the German language from the list of options in Bearbeitungssprache and with English selected for Bearbeitungssprache and Anzeigesprache, the language remains everywhere German.  I do not know enough German to use Microsoft Office in German. When I have tried to change the language into English online, e.g. on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/language-accessory-pack-for-microsoft-365-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f#ID0EBBF=Office_2019,_365, a popup says that the chosen language (i.e. English) is not available on my product ...

Downloading the English language (British or US versions) from Microsoft Office language packs or from within the application makes no difference, the language remains everywhere German.
My operating system is Windows 10, with the default language already set into British English, functioning correctly within the Windows environment. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I have bought and downloaded Microsoft Office 2019 from .....  software-guru.shop -     ................   Purchase from Microsoft Store to avoid these issues.

Comment: I sort of remember MS offers language-locked Office licenses to OEMs...

Comment: Was this software delivered with some sort of license ? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc - There was a 6-digit Produktschlüssel (product key) and a download link, no other license

Comment: @harrymc there are _many_ OEM Office license keys leaked on the Internet and the darknet, so I am guessing it's probably that case.

Comment: @mcendu: Let's hope that this isn't an illegal serial.

Comment: @mcendu - Recent versions of Office 2016 and newer specific are not locked to a specific language. Language packs for Office 2019 and newer are installed through Office itself. [This](https://www.techsoup.org/support/articles-and-how-tos/how-to-download-and-install-microsoft-office-products-requested-from-techsoup) explains how to configure a configuration.xml file for Office.  By doing this will download the appropriate install for your language.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a product key for Office, perhaps the simplest
solution would be to uninstall the current German version
and install an English one. From my experience, the same
Office product key works for all languages.

To download an English Office version, see the article
[How to download Windows and Office ISO files (all versions)](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/easiest-way-legally-download-iso-images-windows-and-office/).

The article contains a detailed description of the download process,
and the main tool it proposes is the
[Microsoft Windows and Office ISO Download Tool](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/easiest-way-legally-download-iso-images-windows-and-office/).